# AHK AltTab and ShiftAltTab not working

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm - This page describes how to map some key combination to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the examples

```
LAlt & j::AltTab
LAlt & k::ShiftAltTab
```

when I write this code it doesn't work and it even disable the regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly on my machine. What Windows/AHK version are you running? I believe `AltTab` is dysfunctional on Windows 8.

Comment: Just to confirm, the posted code worked without issue on my Win 7 system, but failed to function on Win 8. AHK 1.1.13.01 on each.

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/q/449003/122864

Comment: And update to the latest version here http://ahkscript.org/download

Comment: Always use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ (current version, new official website)! AutoHotkey from autohotkey.com is outdated!

Answer (score 1):

This conflict was likely due to an outdated version of AHK conflicting with the OS version being used.

The code has been tested in the newest version of AutoHotkey on Windows 7 and 10, and it works fine.